# How to delete gradle libs?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i have gradle wrapper in my project, i want to delete it?

http://s010.radikal.ru/i312/1502/a3/054abce5c514.png
 How to delete this wrapper without errors? such as

```
Error:(1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
        > Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\MG\M2\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no error , your gradle just turned old , I suggest you upgrade it .

Comment: It's not turned old! It's using the latest one when Gradle plugin is incompatible with the latest one!